# How to link a DLL to an Extjs application

Tags: extjs, dll

I have never used DLLs before so I am such a confused about how to use a DLL into my Extjs app.

How can I link it ?

I don´t really get how it works. I have some parameters that the DLL will use but I don´t know how to link my app to the DLL and make it works with the parameters I have collected from my app.

Comment: I don't think that is possible directly with extjs, you will have to access the dll in what ever you use in the server side

Comment: @FabioBarros: I am quite sure that your comment should be an answer (and the correct one).